Finding the smallest extension field for algebraic number
Suppose I have an algebraic number written in an algebraic extension $Q[\gamma]$. I am looking for a generic procedure to express this number in its smallest possible field extension of $Q$.
For example, consider the number $\sqrt{6}$ in the field $Q[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$, which is represented as $Q[\gamma]$ whose minimal polynomial is $M(x)=x^4-10x^2+1$ with $M(\gamma)=0$. Then $\sqrt{6}=(\gamma^2-5)/2$ in $Q[\gamma]$. Given $M(x)$ and $(\gamma^2-5)/2$, how can I rewrite this expression to $\alpha$ in $Q[\sqrt{6}]$, with $M'(x) = x^2-6, M'(\alpha)=0$?
A more complicated example: for algebraic number $(-295 -2693\gamma -237\gamma^2 -770\gamma^3 -9\gamma^4 -66\gamma^5)/1882$ in $Q[\gamma]$ whose minimal polynomial is $M(x)=13 - 16x + 28x^2 + 2x^3 + 11x^4 + x^6$, I want to obtain $Q[\alpha]$ with $M'(x)=1 + x + x^2$.

I have tried applying this strategy to a more complicated case (see edit) and I do not obtain a vector that only has degree 2 for any $\beta(x)^m \mod M(x)$ (AlgebraicNumber[Root[13 - 16*#1 + 28*#1^2 + 2*#1^3 + 11*#1^4 + #1^6 & , 2, 0], {-295/1882, -2693/1882, -237/1882, -385/941, -9/1882, -33/941} does simplify it).

When I take the polynomial mod, I get: PolynomialMod[(-295/1882 -2693/1882x -237/1882x^2 -385/941x^3 -9/1882x^4  -33/941x^5)^2,13-16x+28x^2+2x^3+11x^4+x^6]=-1587/1882 + (2693*x)/1882 + (237*x^2)/1882 + (385*x^3)/941 + (9*x^4)/1882 +  (33*x^5)/941.

This is indeed contains the original number in the $\gamma$-basis. Thanks!
